# Can I using AES without Base64? (c# or VB.NET)

Tags: c#, vb.net, encryption, aes

Can I use `AES Encryption` without `Base64 encode`? If it is possible, please give me a sample code (`C#` or `VB.Net`)

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Encryption works on bytes and produces bytes. So, in and of itself, yes of course you can use AES without Base 64. However, if you're wanting the input and output to be *strings* then you need to use some form of encoding.

Base 64 is (one of) the most straightforward way of encoding *arbitrary* bytes<sup>1</sup> into strings, but you're free to use another one if you so choose.

<sup>1</sup> Which is what you need to cope with as the output from encryption or the input to decryption.

Answer (score 0):

The specific question that you asked has already been answered by *Damien*. However had you done google you would have got [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Aes_Example
{
    class AesExample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {

                string original = "Here is some data to encrypt!";

                // Create a new instance of the Aes 
                // class.  This generates a new key and initialization  
                // vector (IV). 
                using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
                {

                    // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes. 
                    byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, 
myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

                    // Decrypt the bytes to a string. 
                    string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, 
myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

                    //Display the original data and the decrypted data.
                    Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", original);
                    Console.WriteLine("Round Trip: {0}", roundtrip);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
        static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, 
byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments. 
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            byte[] encrypted;
            // Create an Aes object 
            // with the specified key and IV. 
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key
, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption. 
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt
, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(
csEncrypt))
                        {

                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }


            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream. 
            return encrypted;

        }

        static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key
, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments. 
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

            // Declare the string used to hold 
            // the decrypted text. 
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an Aes object 
            // with the specified key and IV. 
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key
, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption. 
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt
, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(
csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting 
stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            return plaintext;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You,
Your code is console base, But Can I use that code in base winform sir?